# Need to reduce the processing time of python program - Used Thread & vectorization to minimize but doesnt reduce that much time

Tags: python, opencv, vectorization, python-multithreading

I wrote match template program without using inbuilt function from OpenCV library but it is talking 60 seconds to match all the pixel. After i implemented the thread & vectorization in code , it reduced only 13 seconds. Now it is completing within 47 second.

**Can anyone able to help me to process the program within 1 sec without using inbuilt function from OpenCV library.**

Below is my code, please analyze let me know solution how we can reduce the runtime,

Image is attached for testing my code.

[image: 1. data.jpg - Original image]
[image: 2. test.jpg - Template image]

```
import matplotlib.image as img 
import numpy as npy 
import cv2 as cv
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing




def comparison_image(array1,array2,weight,height,total_pixel):
       
    Array_bol = npy.abs(array1 - array2)
    Sum_of_elements = npy.sum(Array_bol)
    
    Matching_percentage = 100 - ((Sum_of_elements/total_pixel) * 100) 
  
    return True , Matching_percentage

         

def Processing(i,j,w3,h3,w1,h1,m1_hsv,m3_hsv,total_pixel):
    
    row_end = i + w3
    col_end = j + h3
    
    array_image_sliced = m1_hsv[i:row_end,j:col_end]

    dest_img,percent = comparison_image(array_image_sliced,m3_hsv,w3,h3,total_pixel)
             
    return percent

def vectorize_func(i,j_iter,w3,h3,w1,h1,m1_hsv,m3_hsv,total_pixel,Result):
    Process = npy.vectorize(Processing,excluded=['i','w3','h3','w1','h1','m1_hsv','m3_hsv','total_pixel'])
    Result[i] = Process(i=i,j=j_iter,w3=w3,h3=h3,w1=w1,h1=h1,m1_hsv=m1_hsv,m3_hsv=m3_hsv,total_pixel=total_pixel)


####starting of program

Starting_seconds = time.time()

m1 = cv.imread('data.jpg')
m3 = cv.imread('test.jpg'); 
 
 
m1_hsv = cv.cvtColor(m1,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
m3_hsv = cv.cvtColor(m3,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  

w1, h1 = m1_hsv.shape
w3, h3  = m3_hsv.shape 
total_pixel = w3*h3*255

j_iter = [val for val in range(0,h1-h3)]

Result = npy.zeros([w1-w3,h1-h3])
Thr_object = []

print(m1_hsv.shape)
print(m3_hsv.shape)


for i in range(w1-w3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=vectorize_func,args=(i,j_iter,w3,h3,w1,h1,m1_hsv,m3_hsv,total_pixel,Result))
    Thr_object.append(t)


for Thread_start in (Thr_object):
    Thread_start.start() 
    
for thread_wait in (Thr_object):
    thread_wait.join()    


highest_matching_percentage = npy.where(Result == npy.max(Result))   
Row_s , col_s = highest_matching_percentage


End_seconds = time.time()

print("TOTAL SECONDS:",End_seconds - Starting_seconds)



dest_img_binary = cv.rectangle(m1,(*col_s,*Row_s),(*col_s+h3,*Row_s+w3),(0,255,0),4)


cv.imshow("output",dest_img_binary)           
cv.waitKey()

    
print("Program end")
```

Comment: are you prepared to implement fourier transforms?

Comment: No @Christoph Rackwitz

Answer (score 0):

[Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) in OpenCV is fast. The [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) in the official docs is pretty good and well worth the time spent.

On my machine, this code runs in 0.13 seconds.

```
import cv2
import time

startTime = time.time()

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0) # open image in gray scale
template = cv2.imread('template.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

# find template
result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)

# use minMaxLoc to search through results and find best match
# for TM_CCOEFF, match will be at maxLoc
minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

# draw white retangle where match is with thickness 8
cv2.rectangle(img, (maxLoc[0], maxLoc[1]), 
                     (maxLoc[0]+w, maxLoc[1]+h), (255, 255, 255), 8)

cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img)

print(time.time() - startTime)
```

Comment: I already know matchtemplate function from OpenCV. Currently i am learning threading & vectorization in python . When i implemented both, it doesnt help to reduce the execution timing. Please tell me how to reduce the running time without using OpenCV functions.